# Bower installation directory changes: sometimes the version is appended

Tags: bower

I have a project that uses bower.

My bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.1",
    ...
```

Then I run bower install.

Then I can see what's installed:

```
➜  myproject git:(develop) ✗ ls app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/
README.md                   angular-sanitize.min.js     bower.json
angular-sanitize.js         angular-sanitize.min.js.map
```

But then a coworker checkouts the project, he `bower install`s, on his machine, this dependency is installed in

`app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/bower-angular-sanitize-v1.2.1/`

instead of my original

`app/bower_components/angular-sanitize/`.

---

So why does bower sometimes adds bower-angular-sanitize-v1.2.1/ to the installation folder ?

*Notes*: We have the same bower.json and version of bower. If I delete my bower_dependencies and reinstall, I still have the old folder.

---

**Edit:**

What I understand (after playing a while with bower install a removing bower_components, clearing bower cache etc)...

My problem is linked to how bower resolves resolutions. It seems that versions are resolved once bower prompts you with a choice for choosing a few version (jquery, angular and bootstrap).

But still, a few things that I don't understand:

- On my machine, even after removing bower cache, removing bower_dependencies or copying the bower.json in a new folder, bower never prompts me about resolutions after a "bower install" (so how are they stored?)
- On my coworker machine, bower prompts for resolutions only on his native system (and not when "bower install"ing in a vagrant machine).

So, I have a few more obscure points:
**How does bower store the dependencies resolutions ? Is there documentation about this anywhere ?** The only place I have found something is on some github issues (and by playing around with it).

My bower.json:

```
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "json3": "~3.2.4",
    "bootstrap-sass": "~2.3.1",
    "es5-shim": "~2.0.8",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.2.1",
    "angular-dragdrop": "<=1.0.4",
    "angular-strap": "~0.7.1",
    "angulartics": "~0.8.4",
    "jquery": "~1.8.3",
    "underscore": "~1.4.4",
    "angular": "1.2.1",
    "angular-route": "1.2.1",
    "angular-resource": "1.2.1",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.2.1",
    "angular-ui-date": "~0.0.3",
    "jquery.masonry": "v2.1.08",
    "bootstrap": "~2.3.1",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.10.0",
    "highcharts": "~3.0.2",
    "jqueryui-timepicker-addon": "~1.4",
    "moment": "~2.0.0",
    "bootstrap-notify": "0.1.0",
    "mjaalnir-bootstrap-colorpicker": "~1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "~1.0.7",
    "angular-scenario": "~1.0.7"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "~1.8.3",
    "angular": "1.2.1",
    "bootstrap": "~2.3.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

We have the same problem here - it seems when the resolutions are defined within `bower.json` on install with empty cache and an empty `bower_components` directory, the package gets installed into `bower_components/package/package-version` whereas if you select the resolutions interactively *during* install, then it gets installed into `bower_components/package` - so if you hit that problem, clean the cache (e.g. `bower cache clean`), delete installed components (e.g. `rm -rf bower_components/`) and remove the `resolutions` from `bower.json` and then `bower install`.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I had to go trough every dependency and install it separately, check its version and then resolving it's resolution when asked. Once it worked and didn't put the folder with the package version number, then I saved the bower.json with the right version and with the resolution (again, when asked to). It worked for me, now all bower dependencies are versioned, no "*" or "latest", and some even without the "~" at the beginning of the version.

Hope this helps you and everyone facing this problem.