# Bower install some components in component/component-@version subfolder

Tags: windows, gulp, bower, bower-install

When I run some bower install based on my bower.json (via bower install), some of my components ouputs in bower_components/component/component-@version.

This happens only on windows, with the same files on Ubuntu, the output is in bower_components/component.

Any ideas on how to fix that ?

my bower.json file :

```js
{
  "name": "myproject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "main": "js/app.js",
  "license": "MIT",
  "private": true,
  "ignore": [
    "**/.*",
    "node_modules",
    "bower_components",
    "tests"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-mocks": "1.3.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "moment": "~2.8.3",
    "accounting": "~0.3.2",
    "lodash": "~2.4.1",
    "angular": "1.3.8",
    "angular-route": "1.3.8",
    "angular-touch": "1.3.8",
    "angular-animate": "1.3.8",
    "angular-sanitize": "1.3.8",
    "angular-cookies": "1.3.8",
    "chartist": "~0.6.1",
    "angular-chartist.js": "~3.0.0",
    "requirejs": "~2.1.11",
    "angular-hotkeys": "chieffancypants/angular-hotkeys#1.4.5",
    "angular-toaster" : "jirikavi/AngularJS-Toaster#0.4.10",
    "ng-csv"  : "asafdav/ng-csv#v0.3.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "chartist": "0.6.1",
    "angularjs": "1.3.8"
  }
}
```

For example, angular-sanitize outputs in *bower_components/angular-sanitize/bower-angular-sanitize-1.3.8* on Windows, but directly in *bower_components/angular-sanitize/* on Ubuntu.

Whereas angular is just outputting its code in *bower_components/angular*, on Windows or on Ubuntu.

Thx for your help :)

Edit : it's not only via gulp, just bower.

Comment: If I make *bower install angular-sanitize --save*, it appears that there's no subfolder created. My thoughts are that the version used has a role.

Comment: I haven't seen this on windows, but have on linux servers when the tmp dir is on a nfs mount.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21384890/bower-installation-directory-changes-sometimes-the-version-is-appended/33267694#33267694 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28545106/bower-installs-same-package-different-in-file-structure/33267671#33267671

Comment: Well, I've switch on linux for this problem. But I'll keep this in mind if some coworkers would have the same problem. Thx :)